# In my Bitcoin Core Wallet I see peers identified as "BitcoinUnlimited" why?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-unlimited

Sometimes I'm checking the connected peers I today I saw one identified as "/BitcoinUnlimited:1.0.2(EB16; AD12)/" User Agent. I haven't saw this before, all I see is Satoshi User Agents.

[image]

It this the hard fork Bitcoin Cash wallet peer? I don't want to help the Bitcoin Cash network, can I ban all peers with this User Agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BitcoinUnlimited](https://www.bitcoinunlimited.info/) is [fork of Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) project, maintained on [github](https://github.com/BitcoinUnlimited/BitcoinUnlimited).

People using BitcoinUnlmited instead of Bitcoin-core are showing that as `User Agent`

`BitcoinUnlimited` offers two builds one for `Bitcoin` and other for `Bitcoin Cash`.

So what you are seeing is people using `BitcoinUnlmited` client for Bitcoin.

You don't have to BAN them, as they are not on `BitcoinCash` network but on `Bitcoin` Network.